# How can I setup multiples Windows Services?

Tags: c#, windows, web-services, service

So, I was creating a windows service and i was following this video to setup the windows service.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tAF9krJu3cs

So, I have a Model, I get the Model in the controller so I can build what I want to send, then, I call that Controller on the Service. After that, I created the Installer. Problem: I have 3 and i was able to create them adding: [RunInstaller(true)] in the beggining of every service. After that, I was saying that they were not manual and "prepraring" them for the errors, starting them, and, after that I started them. But, I turned on one of them, the other turns off, and so on. I was able to turn the 3 on after a while (maybe this was a bug) but they all stopped working again..... My code:

ProjectInstaller:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRdGY.png)

ProjectInstaller.Designer.cs :

```
{
    partial class ProjectInstaller
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary> 
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.serviceProcessInstaller1 = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller();
            this.AccountService = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller();
            this.FinInfoPrevYearService = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller();
            this.GetFinancialInfoService = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller();
            // 
            // serviceProcessInstaller1
            // 
            this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalService;
            this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Password = null;
            this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Username = null;
            this.serviceProcessInstaller1.AfterInstall += new System.Configuration.Install.InstallEventHandler(this.serviceProcessInstaller1_AfterInstall);
            // 
            // AccountService
            // 
            this.AccountService.ServiceName = "AccountService";
            this.AccountService.AfterInstall += new System.Configuration.Install.InstallEventHandler(this.AccountService_AfterInstall);
            // 
            // FinInfoPrevYearService
            // 
            this.FinInfoPrevYearService.ServiceName = "FinInfoPrevYearService";
            this.FinInfoPrevYearService.AfterInstall += new System.Configuration.Install.InstallEventHandler(this.FinInfoPrevYearService_AfterInstall);
            // 
            // GetFinancialInfoService
            // 
            this.GetFinancialInfoService.ServiceName = "GetFinancialInfoService";
            this.GetFinancialInfoService.AfterInstall += new System.Configuration.Install.InstallEventHandler(this.GetFinancialInfoService_AfterInstall);
            // 
            // ProjectInstaller
            // 
            this.Installers.AddRange(new System.Configuration.Install.Installer[] {
            this.serviceProcessInstaller1,
            this.AccountService,
            this.FinInfoPrevYearService,
            this.GetFinancialInfoService});

        }

        #endregion

        private System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller serviceProcessInstaller1;
        private System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller AccountService;
        private System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller FinInfoPrevYearService;
        private System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller GetFinancialInfoService;
    }
}
```

ProjectInstaller.cs:

```
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public partial class ProjectInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
    {
        public ProjectInstaller()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void serviceProcessInstaller1_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void AccountService_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void GetFinancialInfoService_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void FinInfoPrevYearService_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

One of the services:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMWVb.png)

Please help me guys.. I dont know what to do anymore...

Comment: Gotta admit, i'm slightly confused as to whether you're trying to make a windows service (a long running gui-less program that starts and stops under the control of the O/S) or a webservice.. The code clearly is a windows service but the question as a whole seems like you're aiming  to  solve a problem we'd normally apply an asp.net web service(api) to.. That's not to say i fail to appreciate that MVC is a paradigm as well as a Microsofty web technology branding.. it just seems odd to create multiple windows services that apparently each deliver small subsets of data..

Comment: @CaiusJard I am doing it the way I learned.. You gotta keep in mind that I learned all by myself.. This was the only way I saw

Comment: Only way to do what?

Comment: @CaiusJard My problem: When I mark the itens in ERP, they go to a WebService. My windows service is going to consult the webservice, cjeck if there is itens and if yes, create/update itens itens in CRM

That itens can be stock, clients, etc. Thats why I have 3 services. If you have another solution, tell me.

Comment: @CaiusJard the last developer was fired, I am here creating a new WebSerive and the only reference I have is the old webservice and the videos I saw.

Comment: Oh.. erm.. It sounds like a small enough problem that I'd just use one windows service